# If $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue integrable, then $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x+t)-f(x)|dx=0.$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

The problem is stated in the title. If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then the Dominated Convergence Theorem and Lebesgue's Criterion for Riemann integrability does it, however I am stuck when the assumption is only Lebesgue integrability.

Comment: Lusin's theorem says that you can find a set of arbitrarily small measure such that $f$ is continuous when restricted to its complement. Then $f(x+t)\to f(x)$ a.e. on that set. Then you would just need to bound the contribution to the integral on the set of small measure...

Comment: @kccu Lusin's theorem uses the subspace topology. Consider the characteristic function of the rationals. Lusin's theorem gives you that $f$ is continuous restricted to the irrationals. But the limit as $t$ goes to $0$ of $f(x+t)$ does not exist anywhere.

Comment: @EricThoma I remembered the proof using approximations by continuous functions, but couldn't remember exactly how. The answer by ncmathsadist looks like the right method.

Comment: @kccu Sorry, I just wanted to clarify, since Lusin's theorem seems much more useful than it actually is.

Comment: @EricThoma I appreciate that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The continuous functions of compact support $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ are $L^1$ dense in $L^1$.  Now play your typical triangle inequality game and you can make this result work.